# Function Pass-by-value and free allocation

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

Here's a very basic C++ question just want to make sure before I make mistake.

I have a struct `obj` like below:

```
struct obj
{
  BSTR str;
}
```

and in a function `foo`, I initialized a `cComObject<obj> ex`, and allocate memory to str.

Then, in function `foo`, I called function `bar(ex)`(with the variable `ex`).

In this case, do I need to free `ex.str` in function `bar` to avoid heap leak?

Thanks

Comment: why not use **[`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yb2sfxk(v=vs.80).aspx)**? you'll get memory management for free. As well as conversions. See also `_variant_t`

Comment: Please show us some more code (like your hypothetical `foo` and `bar` methods) so that we can help you with it.

Comment: @sehe ahh I was just asking for this particular situation. If I pass a object with heap memory by value, I will need to free it in callee as well right?

Comment: @sehe _bstr_t is good stuff btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *someone* will have to free that `BSTR` to avoid a memory leak. It could be `bar`, or it could be `foo` after `bar` returns. `BSTR` is just a pointer, a typedef for `wchar_t*`.

Note though that you don't normally pass instances of `CComObject` around by value. `CComObject` is meant to be allocated on the heap, and its lifetime managed using reference counting, via `AddRef` and `Release`. Further, `CComObject<C>` expects `C` to be derived from `CComObjectRoot`. Your `obj` class is not so derived.

Comment: Note that BSTRs are technically not just a straight wchar_t* pointer and should usually be allocated/freed with `SysAllocString` and `SysFreeString`.